# Get Imports of a Project in Addin VS2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, msbuild, visual-studio-addins, envdte

I need get a list "Imports" of project in Addin VS 2008 - .NET 3.5.

In VS2010 - .NET 4.0, I use:

```
EnvDTE.Project project = GetProject();
var project1 = new Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project(project.FullName);
project1.Xml.Imports.ForEach(i => {
                    Trace.WriteLine("\t Import Project: " + i.Project); 
});
```

but fails in VS2008 (Microsoft.Build assembly not found).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Using VS2008 and .net 3.5, Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine.Engine is obsolete in .net 4.0

```
    var engine = new Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine.Engine();
    var proj = new Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine.Project(engine);
    proj.Load(project.FullName);
    foreach (Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine.Import import in proj.Imports)
    {
        contieneTargets = import.ProjectPath.ContainsWithStringComparison("Microsoft.VisualStudio.SharePoint.targets", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
        Trace.WriteLine("\t Import Project: " + import.ProjectPath);
        if (contieneTargets) break;
    }
```

Only a problem: when this code is executed several times, I get some error that the project yet loaded.

> System.InvalidOperationException: An equivalent project (a project
>   with the same global properties and tools version) is already present
>   in the project collection, with the path "test.csproj". To load an
>   equivalent into this project collection, unload this project first.